# Write to XML Document which is in My.Settings

Tags: xml, vb.net, datatable

i am trying to save my Datatable to a My.Settings XML Document but its not working and here is my code

```
mainDatatable.WriteXml(My.Settings.mainDatatableXMLDocument.Name)
```

and this is working with normal XML document

```
 mainDatatable.WriteXml("C:\Users\user\Documents\X.xml")
```

Comment: Does it give an error?  If so, what's the error.  If you trace through the code, what does `My.Settings.mainDatatableXMLDocument.Name` return when it gets to that line?

Comment: it returns Object reference not set to instance of object

Answer (score 0):

`My.Settings.mainDatatableXMLDocument` must be null, in which case, accessing the `Name` property of that property will throw the null reference exception.  I would recommend first checking if the setting exists.  For instance:

```vb
If My.Settings.mainDatatableXMLDocument IsNot Nothing Then
    mainDatatable.WriteXml(My.Settings.mainDatatableXMLDocument.Name)
Else
    ' Handle the fact that the setting is missing...
End If
```